# SWRevealViewController delegate nil

Tags: ios, swift, null

at first place I'm just staring with iOS so maybe this is some dummy question but I can't figure it out. I'm using `SWRevealViewController` for side bar menu and I used `delegate` to detect `FrontViewPosition` and have this line of code: `self.revealViewController().delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad` and there problem appears (same thing if I put this line in `viewDidAppear`). I'm using `FirebaseAuth` and have `LoginViewController` so when I login first time exception is thrown

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on line as I said `self.revealViewController().delegate = self`. Of course I can avoid this by simply `nil` checkin but then `revealViewController()` will not work as it is not registered.

Strange thing, at least for me, is next time after `FirebaseAuth` save my credentials and app starts directly on `MainViewController` everything will work. Only problem is when I login first time or log out and login again. I `performSegue` to launch `MainViewController` after login was successful. 
Can someone tell me where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Can you share some of presenting `LoginViewController` and MainViewController  ?

Answer (score 1):

I used `SWRevealViewController` in my project with login screen.

How I did to handle user login is:

1. Make Login viewController as Initial View Controller.
2. Then check for user already logged in or not inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate` file.

   ```
   if (userDefaults.object(forKey:"user") != nil) {
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController")
       self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   }
   ```
3. If user already logged in then present MainViewController.
4. Then added below code in `viewDidLoad` of `MainViewController`.

   ```
   // To show Menu
   if (self.revealViewController() != nil) {
       menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
       menuButton.action =  #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
       self.view.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
   }
   ```

I hope this will helps you.

Comment: I have similar code for example: `openDrawer.addTarget(revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)` but exception is only thrown on `delegate` but I have found something which works in my case. Thank you for your answer and explanation. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I found solution which works in my scenario. Still if someone knows what is the problem please explain. It would be my pleasure to mark your answer as correct one. I don't know is that a bug in `SWRevealViewController` or my approach wasn't correct. So what I did is:

I made checking is user logged in or not in `MainViewController` in `viewWillAppear` like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener() {
        auth, user in
        if user == nil {
            let loginController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController
            self.present(loginController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

After that when user successfuly log in I just `dismiss` the `LoginViewController` and handle the user authentication where is necessary in `MainViewController`. And I tested this approach seems it is working. Same thing I did with `SignUpViewController`
Thanks to everyone who tried to help.